# Is it possible to validate distribution tree during installer build?

Tags: java, install4j

I need to somehow validate if fileset that will be included contains all required files.
Which files to include are listed in file.

Is it even possible to do using install4j? Is possible to run java application during build or some other way validate fileset?

I alreas checked option from 'File option' -> 'Build Option' -> What to do when files are missing at build time. But I need validation according to specific list of files.

Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately, the only real way to validate that is to run the installer (!!) and check that it *has* installed the files that you require it to.  You could do this during the build, or as an extra validation step after the build has completed.  (If you simply check that the files are all there before or while generating the installer, you don't validate that the files are included in the installer intact, or that the generated installer will install them intact in the required location.)

Comment: @StephenC is right. You could also create an additional archive media file, such as a ZIP file to check its contents more easily without executing an installer.